# Separating cell contents into new rows in R

Tags: r

just chasing a solution to separate the contents of a cell into rows, rather than columns. (I considered using the separate command).

Starting format of data:

```
> Orders[c(1,2),]
  ID             Products 
     12345       c("Product X, "Product Y", "Product Z")       
     12346       c("Product X, "Product Y")
```

Trying to get it to look like this:

```
> print(Amended_Orders)
  ID             Products 
     12345       Product X
     12345       Product Y
     12345       Product Z     
     12346       Product X   
     12346       Product Y
```

Any ideas? Cheers x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tidyverse`, we can `unnest` the `list` column to expand the rows

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     unnest(Products)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#     ID Products
#  <dbl> <chr>   
#1 12345 a       
#2 12345 b       
#3 12345 c       
#4 12346 x       
#5 12346 y
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(12345, 12346), Products = list(c("a", "b", 
"c"), c("x", "y"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setNames(data.frame(rep(d$ID, lengths(d$Products)), unlist(d$Products)), names(d))
#OR
do.call(rbind, lapply(asplit(d, 1), function(x) data.frame(lapply(x, unlist))))
```

**Data**

```
d = structure(list(ID = c(12345, 12346), Products = list(c("a", "b", 
"c"), c("x", "y"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```